# How to validate required attribute in marshmallow for create & update operations?

Tags: json, python-3.x, marshmallow

The required validation should be done for create operation whereas for update operation required validation should skip for the below schema with given sample json,

```
class RuleSchema(Schema):
    name = fields.String(required=True)
    code = fields.String(required=True)
    priority_from = fields.Int(required=True)
    priority_to = fields.Int(required=True)

schema = RuleSchema()

# On Create
schema.load({"name": "rule-01", "code":"a000", "priority_from":1, "priority_to":10})  # During Create

# On Update
schema.load({"name": "rule-01", "code":"a000", "priority_to":11})
```

During create operation priority_from & priority_to are mandatory whereas during update operation the priority attributes may/may not come and in such case how to handle the required validation in marshmallow?

Answer (score 0):

For this use case, I'd use two schemas.

There are ways to tweak schemas on-the-fly, but I don't see a simple one for your specific use case, and even then, I find it more readable to have a `RulePostSchema` and a `RulePutSchema`. I do that pretty often to prevent modifying some fields after the initial post.

Let one schema inherit the other to only write the changes you want.

```
class RulePostSchema(Schema):
    name = fields.String(required=True)
    code = fields.String(required=True)
    priority_from = fields.Int(required=True)
    priority_to = fields.Int(required=True)

class RulePutSchema(Schema):
    priority_from = fields.Int()
    priority_to = fields.Int()
```